# how to have nested log groups?

Tags: cypress

I can structure logs into a collapsible group using `groupStart` and `groupEnd` (see e. g. [github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27351)).

```
Cypress.log({name,
             message,
             groupStart: true,
            })
```

Is there a way to nest such groups into a collapsible super group?

Comment: Please advise what that would look like, both invocation and result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice there's also a `groupEnd` property which is implicit at the end of the test.

Using `groupEnd` ***explicitly***, it's fairly trivial to nest groups.

It behaves identically to [console.group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/group_static#examples)

```js
it('log nesting', () => {
  Cypress.log({ name: 'level1', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })
  Cypress.log({ name: 'level2', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })
  Cypress.log({ name: 'level3', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })

  Cypress.log({ name: 'inner', message: 'inside nested groups'})

  Cypress.log({ name: 'level3', message: '- grouping', groupEnd: true })
  Cypress.log({ name: 'level2', message: '- grouping', groupEnd: true })
  Cypress.log({ name: 'level1', message: '- grouping', groupEnd: true })
})
```

[image]

---

**Without the un-nesting log entries**

Call the `.endGroup()` method on the saved log variable to reduce the nesting level.

```js
it('log nesting', () => {
  const level1Log = Cypress.log({ name: 'level1', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })
  const level2Log = Cypress.log({ name: 'level2', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })
  const level3Log = Cypress.log({ name: 'level3', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })

  Cypress.log({ name: 'inner', message: 'inside nested groups'})

  level3Log.endGroup()
  Cypress.log({ name: 'outer2', message: 'outside level 3'})

  const level3aLog = Cypress.log({ name: 'level3a', message: '+ grouping', groupStart: true })

  Cypress.log({ name: 'inner', message: 'inside level 3a group'})
  level3aLog.endGroup()

  level2Log.endGroup()
  Cypress.log({ name: 'outer1', message: 'outside level 2'})

  level1Log.endGroup()
  Cypress.log({ name: 'outer', message: 'outside all nested groups'})
})
```

[image]

---

**Typescript**

If you are concerned about these options being omitted from the type definition, add a `.d.ts` file to the project to make them publicly available.

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface LogConfig {
    groupStart: Boolean
    groupEnd: Boolean
  }

  interface Log { 
    endGroup(): void
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem, though: if I do `.set({groupEnd: true})` and then start a new log group, it gets nested into the old one, but it should not.`.set({groupEnd: true})` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: There seems to be a bug, but you can change `cy.state()` as a work-around. I'll see if I can  find the bug.

Comment: There's an `endGroup()` method that is more convenient than direct state updates - added to the second example above.

Comment: Great! I still got `Property 'endGroup' does not exist on type 'Log'`, though. Also there is no `endGroup` in the `log.d.ts` code snippet you(?) provided. As a workaround I added `interface Log { endGroup(): any }` in my `declare namespace Cypress {` ...

Comment: Indeed, I mistook `groupEnd()` for `endGroup()`. There seems to be some defunct code around this feature.